# Message Handler using Python Telegram Bot Not Changing State

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm trying to ask to the user to insert his name using MessageHandler but it doesn't change the state.
The bot doesn't enter in `name` method.

```
class Pos(Enum):
    NAME = 0

async def chat(update, context) -> int:
    await update.message.reply_text('Insert your name:)')
    print(Pos.NAME.value)
    return Pos.NAME.value
  
async def name(update, context) -> int:
    name = update.message.text    
    await update.message.reply_text(f'Your name is {name}!')
    return ConversationHandler.END


def main() -> None:
    application = Application.builder().token("MY_TOKEN").build()

    application.add_handler(
        ConversationHandler(
            entry_points=[CommandHandler("chat", chat)],
            states={
                Pos.NAME.value: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, name)]
            },
            fallbacks=[],
        )
    )

    application.run_polling()
```

I thought that it was because of my `NAME` tag, before I had `NAME = range(1)` instead of that classe, but that was giving me the output `range(0,1)` and wasn't changing the state anyways.

What can be the problem here?